# Loop of creation via a user input, WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-code, repeat

The system needs a way of taking input from txtBox.
I then need the system to take the number input, 1-10. And repeat the ticket and file creation for that x amount of times.
This code also creates a file on the pc with the Lottery ticket in it.
the files have to be named LottoKupon1, LottoKupon2 and so on, this needs to match user input of course.

**this is for creation of file and folder**

```
namespace Lottery
{
    internal class FolderCreater
    {
        static string folderName = @"C:\lotto";
        public static string fileName = @"C:\lotto\LottoKupon.txt";

        public static void CreateFolder()
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(folderName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
            }
            else if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                File.Create(fileName);
            }
            else { }
        }
    }
}
```

**This is for creation of Lottry Ticket**

```
namespace Lottery
{
    // the system needs a way of taking input
    // from txtBox, int user = int.Parse(txtBox.Text.Trim());  which this line does
    // i then need the system to take the number input, 1-10. 
    // and repeat the ticket and file creation for that x amount of times.
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public List<long> ListOfAllArrays = new List<long>();
        int i = 1;
        

        Random randNum = new Random();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Lotto ()
        {
            

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FolderCreater.fileName);
           

           
             sw.WriteLine("    " + "Lotto " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy\n"));
             sw.WriteLine("         " + "1-uge\n" + "       LYN-LOTTO\n");
             Random randNum = new Random();
             int[][] AllArrays = new int[10][];
             for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
             {
                AllArrays[i] = new int[7];
             }
             int RowNr = 0;
             foreach (int[] row in AllArrays)
             {
                RowNr++;
                sw.Write(RowNr + ". ");
                for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
                {
                    int number = randNum.Next(1, 37);
                    while (row.Any(n => n == number))
                    {
                        number = randNum.Next(1, 37);
                    }
                    row[j] = number;
                }

                Array.Sort(row);
                for(int l = 0; l < 7; l++)
                {
                    sw.Write(row[l].ToString("00") + " ");
                }
                sw.Write("\n");
             }
             TestIfSame(AllArrays);

                if (CheckBox.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("\n****** Joker Tal ******");
                    int[][] AllJokerRows = new int[2][];
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    {
                        AllJokerRows[i] = new int[7];
                    }
                    foreach (int[] n in AllJokerRows)
                    {
                        sw.Write(" ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                        {
                            var JokerNumber = randNum.Next(1, 10);
                            n[i] = JokerNumber;
                        }
                        Array.Sort(n);
                        for (int u = 0; u < 7; u++)
                        {
                            sw.Write(n[u] + "  ");
                        }
                        sw.Write("\n");
                    }
                }
                sw.Close();
            

        }

        public void TestIfSame(int[][] AllArrays)
        {
            //List<long> ListOfAllArrays = new List<long>();
            for (int i = 0; i < AllArrays.Length; i++)
            {
                ListOfAllArrays.Add(MakesLongNumber(AllArrays[i]));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < AllArrays.Length; i++)
            {
                long temp = ListOfAllArrays[0];
                ListOfAllArrays.Remove(ListOfAllArrays[0]);

                if (ListOfAllArrays.Contains(MakesLongNumber(AllArrays[i])))
                {
                    Lotto();
                }
                else
                {
                    ListOfAllArrays.Add(temp);
                }
            }
            long MakesLongNumber(int[] row)
            {
                string a = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
                {
                    a += row[i].ToString();
                }
                return Convert.ToInt64(a);
            }
        }
        private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        
        private void cmdOk_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FolderCreater.CreateFolder();
            Lotto();
            // add a ListBox.Items.Add(); within this needs to be the command for the Lottery ticket, so i can have it shown on a list box.
        }
```

**This is for a Lottery assignment, its on a lower level of coding, so no answer that is way too complicated, hope you understand. please ask questions if needed.

I tried a dew things with a for loop around the first void which took user input, but i could not make it work.

the code is expected to create files and Lottery ticket depending on users input**

Comment: You need to separate the `If` branches when creating the folder/file since both cases can occur (no folder and no file exists).

Comment: how would you do this?
i see what you mean, but cant really get it done.

Comment: Two separate if branches, one for the directory and one for the file. `if (!Directory.Exists(folderName)) { ...}` No `else if` or `else`.

Comment: Public static void CreateFolder()
if (!Directory.Exists(folderName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
            }

Public static void CreateFile()
 if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                File.Create(fileName);
            }

Comment: I think the point of an assignment is that the pupil learns by doing the assignment. Otherwise the pupil just "learns" cut and paste.